# Replace apostrophe in a dynamically created insert statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have created a lookup table which holds `Insert` statements. Some of the values in the values have apostrophes in them.

The value appears like this

```
'SCRW, PAN-HD PHIL, THR'D: 8-32. L: 3/8""'
```

Whole statement is:

```
INSERT INTO PARTS_BOMD (BOM_ID, ITEM_REV, ITEM_CN, ITEM_NUMBER, ITEMNUMBER, FINDNUM, QTY, ITEMDESCRIPTION, ITEMREV, ITEMSIZE, REFDES, BOMTEXT02, ITEMLIST21, SUMMARYCOMPLIANCE, BOMMULTITEXT30, BOMNOTES, ITEMLIST10, BOMLIST01, BOMLIST03, BOMLIST02, ITEMTEXT22, ITEMTEXT23, ITEMLIFECYCLEPHASE, ITEMP2MULTILIST05, ITEMTEXT15, RNUM) VALUES (2009034062,'31','ECO05447','1472096','1422042','100','4','SCRW, PAN-HD PHIL, THR'D: 8-32. L: 3/8""','A0 MPL03682','PC','PC','','6 out of 6 Compliant','Missing Info','Missing Info','','ZHLB','','','X','','','AREL','Yes','0.10220',582272);
```

This table have more than 4 million records and this issue occurs most of the time.

Is there any way I can change this apostrophe into two single quotes.

I am using SQL Server 2014.

Oracle scripts which generates these insert statements:

```
set serveroutput on size 100000
set feedback off

declare
  v_table_name      varchar2(30) := 'PARTS_BOMD';  -- Your Tablename
  v_column_list     varchar2(2000);
  v_insert_list     varchar2(2000);
  v_ref_cur_columns varchar2(4000);
  v_ref_cur_query   varchar2(2000);
  v_ref_cur_output  varchar2(2000);
  v_column_name     varchar2(2000);
  cursor c1 is select column_name, data_type from user_tab_columns where table_name = v_table_name order by column_id;
  refcur            sys_refcursor; 
begin
  for i in c1 loop
     v_column_list := v_column_list||','||i.column_name;
     if i.data_type = 'NUMBER' then
        v_column_name := i.column_name;
     elsif i.data_type = 'DATE' then
        v_column_name := chr(39)||'to_date('||chr(39)||'||chr(39)'||'||to_char('||i.column_name||','||chr(39)||'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss'||chr(39)||')||chr(39)||'||chr(39)||', '||chr(39)||'||chr(39)||'||chr(39)||'dd/mm/rrrr hh:mi:ss'||chr(39)||'||chr(39)||'||chr(39)||')'||chr(39);
     elsif i.data_type = 'VARCHAR2' then
        v_column_name := 'chr(39)||'||i.column_name||'||chr(39)';
     end if;
     v_ref_cur_columns := v_ref_cur_columns||'||'||chr(39)||','||chr(39)||'||'||v_column_name;
  end loop; 
  v_column_list     := ltrim(v_column_list,',');
  v_ref_cur_columns := substr(v_ref_cur_columns,8);

  v_insert_list     := 'INSERT INTO '||v_table_name||' ('||v_column_list||') VALUES ';
  v_ref_cur_query   := 'SELECT '||v_ref_cur_columns||' FROM '||v_table_name;

  open refcur for v_ref_cur_query;
  loop
  fetch refcur into v_ref_cur_output; 
  exit when refcur%notfound;
    v_ref_cur_output := '('||v_ref_cur_output||');'; 
    v_ref_cur_output := replace(v_ref_cur_output,',,',',null,');
    v_ref_cur_output := replace(v_ref_cur_output,'(,','(null,');
    v_ref_cur_output := replace(v_ref_cur_output,',,)',',null)');
    v_ref_cur_output := replace(v_ref_cur_output,'null,)','null,null)');
    v_ref_cur_output := v_insert_list||v_ref_cur_output; 
    --dbms_output.put_line (v_ref_cur_output); 
    INSERT INTO BOM_INS_LOOKUP(LOOKUP_STATMENT)
    VALUES (v_ref_cur_output);
    COMMIT;
  end loop; 
end;
/
```

It ain't much but it does the job.

Comment: You can easily use REPLACE to "fix" this issue. I would suggest though that if you have a table with 4 million insert statements you are doing something horribly wrong. This sounds like a case of needing stored procedures instead of storing queries like this.

Comment: Do you need a fix for the already generated statements or would you settle with a fix for the statements generation code?

Comment: As a follow up to my previous comment. Consider how absurdly difficult your life will be if you make a change to one of your tables. You have to update 4 million insert statements as opposed to a single stored procedure.

Comment: Actually the statements are generated from Oracle using a PL/SQL. This is the only way I can import data into SQL Server as I can not use links, import from .csv .txt or any other format.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz it will be good if the fix is for the already generated statements, as moving the file from client machine to our local is another headache. And I tried to replace an apostrophe using replace, it also updates quotes used for the strings in an insert statement.

Comment: The correct approach would be to double the quotes while creating the Oracle output.

Comment: @shawnt00 I have updated the question, can you please guide me where to put that check in my PL/SQL code of Oracle.

Comment: Use `replace(<column>, '''', '''''')` instead of the bare column name in your column list.

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't an easy way to approach this problem generically. How would you go about processing a list of values like this one?: `'A',',','B'` Is it one or two or three values? And there are *two* ways to split it into two values.

Here's an approach you might take by making some assumptions about the format.

```
declare @pos int;
declare @s varchar(1024);

declare myCursor for select <COLUMN> from T;
open myCursor;

while @@fetch_status = 0
begin 

    fetch next from myCursor into @s;

    set @pos = charindex(@s, '''', @pos);
    while @pos > 0
    begin
        /* if apostrophe is followed by comma plus apostrophe
           then assume this is the delimiter */
        if substring(@s +',''', @pos + 1, 2) <> ','''
            set @s = stuff(@s, @pos, 1, '''''');
        else
            set @pos = @pos + 2;
       set @pos = charindex(@s, '''', @pos);
    end

    update T set <COLUMN> = @s where current of myCursor;
end

close myCursor;
deallocate myCursor;
```

It would be better to avoid the problem in the first place by properly quoting the values as the `INSERT` queries are generated. There are many ways to export data from Oracle that can be readily picked up by SQL Server.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I solved it by creating a dummy permanent table in Oracle and updating apostrophes with double quotes and then loaded sql insert statements in SQL Server. It executed successfully.